# Laravel Mix BrowserSync reloading

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, browser-sync, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix with React. I have configured BrowserSync reloading after 850 milliseconds `reloadDelay: 850` but sometimes it takes more than 850 milliseconds for Webpack to compile all my JS files. My page gets reloaded before all my files finish compiling, so I have to refresh my page every time manually.

Is there any method to configure Laravel Mix in such a way that it only reloads after compilation completes other than the `reloadDelay` option? I don't want to increase further my `reloadDelay` value.

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .browserSync({
     proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
     reloadDelay: 850,
     files: [
        'resources/js/**/*.js'
     ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a set up that works with browser sync version 2.26.7. Something I also found very useful was this part of the docs, [browser sync recipes](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/recipes). You literally just type in `browser-sync recipe {recipe-name}`.

i.e. `browser-sync recipe webpack.react-transform-hmr`

Given that you have `browser-sync` installed globally on your machine.

```
mix.browserSync({
  watch: true,
  files: [
    'public/js/**/*',
    'public/css/**/*',
    'public/**/*.+(html|php)',
    'resources/views/**/*.php'
  ],
  open: "http://my-site.local/",
  browser: "google chrome",
  reloadDelay: 1000,
  proxy: {
    target: "http://my-site.local/",
    ws: true,
  },
});
```

Theres the full code snippet below on how I connected my react app with Laravel Nova (Im using Laravel Nova so my file paths my look slightly different)

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-imagemin');

// Copy and Convert images
mix.copy('resources/images', 'public/images')
   .imagemin('images/**/*');

// Compile and Copy css custom style files
mix.sass('resources/sass/form.scss', 'public/css')
   .minify('public/css/form.css');

mix.sass('resources/sass/main.scss', 'public/css')
   .minify('public/css/main.css');

mix.sass('resources/sass/nav.scss', 'public/css')
   .minify('public/css/nav.css');

// Copy css vendor files
mix.copy('resources/css/vendor/bootstrap-grid.min.css', 'public/css/vendor');

mix.copy('resources/css/vendor/normalize.css', 'public/css/vendor')
   .minify('public/css/vendor/normalize.css');

// Copy js vendor files
mix.copy('resources/js/vendor/modernizr-3.8.0.min.js', 'public/js/vendor');
mix.copy('resources/js/vendor/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js', 'public/js/vendor');
mix.copy('resources/js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', 'public/js/vendor');

// Compile react
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.browserSync({
  watch: true,
  files: [
    'public/js/**/*',
    'public/css/**/*',
    'public/**/*.+(html|php)',
    'resources/views/**/*.php'
  ],
  open: "http://my-site.local/",
  browser: "google chrome",
  reloadDelay: 1000,
  proxy: {
    target: "http://my-site.local/",
    ws: true,
  },
});
```

This will open your browser on http://localhost:3000 and when you save your changes your browser should reload.

NB!! I wasnt able to get the live reload working when you have a browser tab open on `http://my-site.local/`, however if I open `http://my-site.local:3000` live reload works like a charm.

Happy coding =)